# How to "become a fan" by Facebook API without leaving iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-page

I'd like to allow user to "become a fan" of certain Facebook page in my iPhone app. How can I do that without leave my app, i.e.:

- user choose to "become a fan" of a predefined page
- Facebook login dialog shows up within app
- the app sends "become a fan" request via Facebook API
- the Facebook dialog closes and return to app

Some source code samples will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this method](http://mobileorchard.com/opening-the-facebook-app-to-your-facebook-fan-page/) on how to allow the user to become a fan on the iPhone. The problem here is that the user will leave your application and must have the Facebook app installed on his deviec...

Comment: I can't get that method to work. No matter what NSURL I use, the facebook app opens to a blank page, if not connecting to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the method suggested by ibeitia, it currently doesn't work reliably. There is a known bug in the Facebook application which displays a blank screen instead of your facebook page (unless the user's last action was visiting another profile page).

You can follow up here:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14899